# What NPM CLI command can be used to update a dependency of a dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

**CURRENTLY**

I have `immer` as a dependency in 2 locations.

```
+-- aws-amplify@4.3.1
| `-- @aws-amplify/datastore@3.4.7
|   `-- immer@9.0.6
`-- react-scripts@4.0.3
  `-- react-dev-utils@11.0.4
    `-- immer@8.0.1
```

**ISSUE**

The older version of `immer` has a critical vulnerability. I need to update the dependency.

**QUESTION**

What is the CLI command to update the older immer dependency?

**Notes**

- I have been searching for an answer to this for a while, and I suspect the solution is super easy because I cannot find any answer to this question.
- I have tried `npm update immer` and `npm --depth 5 update immer` and neither solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### Part 1

*Consider this part an academic answer only. Do not use in real life projects.*

To strictly answer your question:

> What is the CLI command to update the older immer dependency?

You can use npm shrinkwrap to manage nested dependencies manually:

```
npm shrinkwrap
```

This will rename `package-lock.json` to `npm-shrinkwrap.json`. They are the same, except `npm-shrinkwrap.json` can be manually edited to set the dependency version.
In this case, find `"immer": "8.0.1"` in the shrinkwrap file and update it to your desired version:

```
  "node_modules/react-dev-utils": {
  "version": "11.0.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/react-dev-utils/-/react-dev-utils-11.0.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-...",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "immer": "8.0.1", <== Change this to "9.0.6"
```

then remove this block to allow npm to use the updated version:

```
  "node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/immer": {
    "version": "8.0.1",
    "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/immer/-/immer-8.0.1.tgz",
    "integrity": "sha512-...",
    "funding": {
      "type": "opencollective",
      "url": "https://opencollective.com/immer"
    }
  },
```

Afterwards you can run `npm i` and then check your dependencies:

```
$ npm i
$ npm list immer

playground@1.0.0 /private/tmp/playground
├─┬ aws-amplify@4.3.2
│ └─┬ @aws-amplify/datastore@3.4.8
│   └── immer@9.0.6
└─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3
  └─┬ react-dev-utils@11.0.4
    └── immer@9.0.6 deduped
```

Keep in mind that upgrading nested dependencies manually may result in undesirable effects. In this case upgrading `immer` that is used by `react-dev-utils` to `9.0.6` could break part of `react-dev-utils` functionality because `immer@9.0.9` is a major version ahead of `8.0.1`. Major versions can include backwards incompatible changes.

You might end up breaking part of your tools due to a vulnerability that does not impact you at all; and checking for the exact usage of `immer` in `react-dev-utils` and making sure the usage is compatible with `9.0.6` could be quite time consuming.

### Part 2

*This is an attempt to solve the problem without answering your question*

To address the problem:

> The older version of immer has a critical vulnerability.

Not all vulnerabilities impact your end users. This particular vulnerability was [reported on create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11523) and was classified as a "development only" issue which does not impact the users because it will not be in the code that runs on their browsers.

More info on this is available on [another issue on create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174).

My usual steps to address vulnerabilities:

1. Upgrade all dependencies to latest stable versions if possible
2. If the vulnerability persists, read the advisory page to understand if it impacts me. `npm audit` provides the details. Keep in mind that vulnerabilities in development tools are not necessarily a problem for users.
3. Visit the npm page of the top-level dependency, go to its issue tracker and report it if it hasn't been reported
4. If the project accepts contributions and the fix is fairly simple, open a pull request and offer to help.
5. Last resort: downgrade, upgrade nested dependency to a breaking version, replace the package if it is not maintained

In this case, maintainers of `create-react-app` have seen and advised this is a false positive in the context of a build tool.

Comment: Dan Abramov has a GREAT explanation here as to why these are NOT actual vulnerabilities: [Help, npm audit says I have a vulnerability in react-scripts! issue #11174](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11174)

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use `npm i`. If this doesn't work you could delete the node modules folder and type `npm i`

Comment: How does this solve the OP's issue? `npm i` is just an alias for `npm install` which will recursively install the dependencies in `package.json` and still default to the vulnerable version of the nested package